# How does the Kubernetes HPA(HorizontalPodAutoscaler) determine which pod's metrics should be used if multiple PODs have the same metrics

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, hpa

suppose we have below HPA(HorizontalPodAutoscaler) deployed in the demo namespace, and multiple pods (POD-A,POD-B) in this demo namespace have the same metric "istio_requests_per_second", How does the HPA determine the metric "istio_requests_per_second" from which pod should be used? Or every POD with this metric will be evaluate against the HPA target?

```html
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: httpbin
spec:
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metric:
        name: istio_requests_per_second
      target:
        type: AverageValue
        averageValue: "10"
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: httpbin
```

test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using prometheus then its the adapter thats correlating between k8's pod name and what metric value to return. Basically the HPA is asking the prometheus adapter for metric `istio_requests_per_second`. By calling `/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/myNamespace/pods/mypod` the adapter takes that and looks at its rules configured for what it should query for.

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/prometheus-adapter/blob/master/docs/config-walkthrough.md

Comment: My question is if multiple PODS have the same metric "istio_requests_per_second", which POD's metric will be used? cause we didn't specify the POD in the HPA. or every POD with this metric will be used, and anyone of them meet the target will trigger the auto-scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, I think HPA uses the 'scaleTargetRef' to determine which POD's metrics should be used, and pull these metrics from the metrics server and evaluate them against the target config.

Answer (score 0):

As per Kubernetes documentation:

> For object metrics and external metrics, a single metric is fetched, which describes the object in question. This metric is compared to the target value, to produce a ratio as above. In the autoscaling/v2 API version, this value can optionally be divided by the number of Pods before the comparison is made.

It will calculate the ratio based on the mean across the target pods.

References:

1.-https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#how-does-a-horizontalpodautoscaler-work